# How to upload a file to AWS S3 bucket from CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: amazon-s3, console, cakephp-3.0, fatal-error, aws-sdk

I have used S3 bucket to upload documents from my CakePHP 2.0 Web Application.

Right now I am facing problem to upload from CakePHP 3.0 Shell script.
I get 
 `Fatal Error: Class S3 not found in App\Shell\S3.php`,
I have googled a lot, 
I have tried to use S3 SDK but if you try to use S3 class in your Shell script I get above error.
 
Please let me know if I am missing something, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like a problem with autoloading the S3 SDK. Have you included the S3 SDK's autoloader properly?

Anyway, I'd recommend PHP league's flysystem for a very easy-to-use abstraction of S3: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3